# A bartender and a customer roll a six-sided, ungalvanized cube. What is his chance of winning?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A bartender and a customer roll a six-sided, ungalvanized cube. If the
> visitor throws a higher number than the bartender, he wins. A guest is
> a rascal who cheats. He takes advantage of the waiter's inattention by
> secretly looking at his first roll under the dice cup and then, if he
> throws a 1-3, he throws the dice again, unnoticed.
>
> What is his chance of winning?

Let $k$ be the number the bartender throws:
For every $k$ there are two ways of winning: Either the visitor has a higher number with his first throw or he throws either a $1$, $2$ or $3$ and than has a higher number.

For $k=6$: $0/6$

For $k=5$: $1/6+3/6\cdot 1/6 $

For $k=4$: $2/6+3/6\cdot2/6$

For $k=3$: $3/6+3/6\cdot3/6$

For $k=2$: $4/6+2/6\cdot4/6$

For $k=1$: $5/6+1/6\cdot5/6$

Adding all these up and dividing them by six, gives $p=\frac{121}{216}$

Is that correct?

Comment: This is not clear.  From your calculation, it appears that you are solving a different problem.  Specifically, you appear to be addressing the problem "suppose the guest knows the bartender's roll  and re-rolls his die if and only if his first roll would fail to win."  But that's not what you were asked.  Also, you fail to solve the alternate problem correctly.

Comment: What happens when there is a draw? this wasn't mentioned in the question. I think the flaw is your answer is that it assumes a draw isn't possible, for example you are saying that if a bartender rolls a 6 the visitor has 0 probability of winning, what if the visitor rolls a 6 too?

Comment: @Sergio A draw means that the bartender won.

Comment: @lulu I tried brute force method on this problem. Did you notice that I divide everything by six at thend?

Comment: Dividing by $6$ is not the problem.  As I say, your calculation appears to presuppose that the guest (sometimes at least) takes the bartender's roll into consideration.  That's why your second term sometimes has a $\frac 36$ term and sometimes has a lesser term.  Brute force ought to work just fine here.

Comment: To stress;  the problem specifies that the guest re-rolls iff he gets $<4$.  Period.  At no point can the cheater use the bartender's roll to shape the option.  It is, of course, better for the guest if they can use knowledge of the bartender's roll, but this was never specified.

Comment: @lulu would it be a correct idea to consider these as 2 dices, one fair dice for the bartender and another unfair dice for the visitor where the probability of rolling between 1 and 3 is 1/36  for each value while the probability of rolling between 4 and 6 is 1(1-3/36)/3 for each value? this came to my mind but I don't know if I am thinking in a wrong way

Comment: @lulu Wow, that makes the problem harder for me. But you're right.

Comment: What should also be clarified : Can the guest only reroll once or as often as he wants ? (My interpretation of the text would be "once")

Comment: Yes, Peter, that is correct - once. That is indeed not that clear.

Comment: @Sergio Your concept is fine, but I am not sure of your arithmetic.  The probability of getting a $1$ with the unfair die is $\frac {1}2\times \frac 16=\frac 1{12}$, as you must get $≤3$ the first time and then throw a $1$.  Same for $2,3$.  For $4$ and up the probability is $\frac 16+\frac 1{12}=\frac 14$ as you can either get the given roll the first time, or get $≤3$ and then throw the desired level.

Comment: @lulu point from making it one unfair die and another fair one is that we now picture them as one roll instead of two, as the probability of the unfair dice takes into account both rolls, so given the fair dice, the probability of rolling one is $\frac{1}{6}*\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{36}$ so in the unfair dice the probability of rolling the number one is $\frac{1}{36}$

Comment: @Sergio  I agree that this is the way to go.  For example, the cheater has a $\frac 14$ chance of throwing a $4$ and then a $\frac 36$ chance of winning with that $4$, for a probability of $\frac 18$.  And so on for each value.  Pretty easy sum, really.  But,m again, I am not sure of your arithmetic. The probability of throwing a $1$ with the unfair die is $\frac 1{12}$, not $\frac 1{36}$.

Comment: Once we have the probabilities (I wanted to point out the mistakes virtually simultaneously to lulu's post), the rest should be easy considering that the guest must actually have a higher result (although it is not explicitely stated that he loses otherwise)

Comment: Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

The stated solution is incorrect because the calculation allows the cheater to (sometimes) consider the bartender's roll, contrary to the specified problem.

To solve the given problem:

We consider probabilities for the various outcomes for the cheater's roll.  For $≤3$ the only way to get that value is to first roll $3$ or less and then roll the specified value.  For $≥4$ the cheater can either get the desired roll initially or get $≤3$ the first time and then roll the desired value.  Thus:

$$ P(X=n) =
\begin{cases}
\frac 1{12}  & \text{if $n≤3$ } \\ \\
\frac 14 & \text{if $n≥4$ }
\end{cases}$$

Where, of course, $X$ is the cheater's roll.

Since the probability of winning if $X=i$ is $\frac {i-1}6$ we see that the probability the cheater wins is $$\frac 1{12}\times \left(\frac 06+\frac 16+\frac 26\right)+\frac 1{4}\times \left(\frac 36+\frac 46+\frac 56\right)=\boxed {\frac {13}{24}}$$

Answer (score 0):

No. The key observation here is that the first roll only counts if it is a 4 or above. This does not have any effect on your $k = 3,4,5,6$ cases, but does on the others: you have counted the case where the customer rolls a $2$ or $3$ on the first roll as a win when it exceeds the bartender's roll, but in fact those will be rerolled, and so have only a $\frac{4}{6}$ or $\frac{5}{6}$ chance of being wins, depending on the bartender's roll.